# Get selected remote file via Remote System Explorer (RSE)'s API?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rse

I'm developing a custom Eclipse plugin that makes use of Remote System Explorer (of the [Eclipse TM project](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/)) under the hoods.

My question is, how can I grab the currently selected [remote file](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/rse/subsystems/files/core/subsystems/RemoteFile.html) from my own plugin? I suppose there is some convenience method somewhere, but I can't find it (or I found a number of close matches, but couldn't get anything to work).

Comment: What do you mean by grab it - get a reference to the selected object, or get the contents of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make use of the selection service.
[There is an article here that will help.](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html)

Comment: Thanks ... indeed looks like this is the case ... will test asap. I'll accept your answer in the meanwhile.